# Pattern failure with grok due a longer integer in a column

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok, logstash-grok

I have used grok debugger to get the top format working and it is being seen fine by elasticsearch. Eventually, when a log line like the one below hit it shoots out a tag with "grokparsefailure" due to the extra space before each integer (I'm assuming). Is there a tag I can use to accept anything no matter how long or short for each column?

```
0000003B 2015-03-14 07:46:14.618 16117 16121

00000DA1 2015-03-14 07:45:54.609  6382  6382
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or more spaces between two integers:

```
%{INT} +%{INT}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use the built in logstash pattern %{SPACE} to match any number of whitespace characters.

`%{INT:num1}%{SPACE}%{INT:num2}`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a custom filter since I knew my values were between 4-5 characters and then used patterns_dir => "./patterns" in my conf file.

```
_ID [0-9A-F]{4,5}

_ID2 [0-9A-F]{4,5}
```

UPDATE*****

my solution did not work because the number can be anywhere from 3 to 6 characters. The easier solution was provided above. Marked as answer.